# How can i get Selected Kendo Grid cell Value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code to display the selected KendoGrid Row in a form. I used this code it looks like it will take me to what i want to accomplish but I need help instead of displaying only the first cell, i also want to display the rest of  values and display in the form as `$("#ID").val(value);`

which only displays the first `<td>` text but i want to

```
      $("#AddressGrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var ID= row.find("td:first").text();
          $("#ID").val(ID);// this display the selected row first cell in #ID text form but i want to access the rest of cell
        console.log(ID);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the line `row.find("td:first")` selects only first td of the row. So, you should use `row.find("td")` instead and iterate through all the results to access each cell of the grid. E.g.

```
$("#AddressGrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var textVal = "";
    row.find("td").each(function(i, r) {
        textVal += `Col ${i+1}: ${r.innerText}\n`;
    });
    alert(textVal);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rabink!! Nice It works but  how can i display   AddressLine1 in AddressLine1 textbox or in #AddressLine1 or col 2  and  AddressLine2/col 3...

Comment: Sure, why not? The cells goes in sequential order. You can put all the ids of the textboxes in an array and fill accordingly. Or, if you want only selected cells' value to be filled you can compare the index `i` value and fill. I am not sure how long will this dojo link be available, I've written an example here. http://dojo.telerik.com/ajAYekAw

Comment: i tried it as `  $("#AddressLine1").val(`Col ${2}: ${r.innerText}`);` but no luck any idea?

Comment: You are not getting it correct, the value is just `r.innerText`. I've used `Col ${2}` just to denote the corresponding cell number. Have you looked at the dojo I've provided? Or, can you create a dojo and share?

Comment: Ah, ya i notice that, i will try that. Thank you so much!